# How to launch activity with NFC and then allow different tags to be scanned on same activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, android-applicationrecord

I have a basic Android application and need to implement the ability for an NFC swipe to launch a specific Activity. I have achieved this by writing an *Android Application Record*. I then need for further swipes to use the same Activity rather than launching new ones.

The Android Application Record launches the Activity as expected. I then fire up a create a Pending Intent and in OnResume, set up a foreground dispatch

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_plant);

    // initialize NFC
    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    nfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, this.getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");

    super.onResume();

    enableForegroundMode();

    doTagOperations(getIntent());
}

public void enableForegroundMode() {
    Log.d(TAG, "enableForegroundMode");

    IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED); // filter for all
    IntentFilter[] writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] {tagDetected};
    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, nfcPendingIntent, writeTagFilters, null);
}
```

I then have a method that does tag related activities. This looks as follows:

```
private void doTagOperations(Intent intent) {

    Log.i(TAG, intent.getAction());
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

        textView.setText("Hello NFC!");

        Parcelable[] messages = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if (messages != null) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Found " + messages.length + " NDEF messages"); // is almost always just one

            vibrate(); // signal found messages :-)

            // parse to records
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                try {
                    List<Record> records = new Message((NdefMessage)messages[i]);

                    Log.d(TAG, "Found " + records.size() + " records in message " + i);

                    for(int k = 0; k < records.size(); k++) {
                        Log.d(TAG, " Record #" + k + " is of class " + records.get(k).getClass().getSimpleName());

                        Record record = records.get(k);
                        if(records.get(k).getClass().getSimpleName().equals("TextRecord")) {
                            String plant = new String(records.get(k).getNdefRecord().getPayload());
                            Log.i(TAG, plant);
                            textView.setText(plant);
                        }
                        if(record instanceof AndroidApplicationRecord) {
                            AndroidApplicationRecord aar = (AndroidApplicationRecord)record;
                            Log.d(TAG, "Package is " + aar.getDomain() + " " + aar.getType());
                        }

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Problem parsing message", e);
                }

            }
        }
    } else {
        // ignore
    }
}
```

My issue is that the system behaves in an odd way. You can launch the Activity with the tag but a second swipe will launch a new Activity. Further swipes will then use the existing Activity but the Intent will always appear to be the same. I attempt to read a text record from the tag and this should change based on the tag I have swipe - but it doesn't. It's as if the method by which I grab the Intent is always picking up the same one irrespective of the tag swiped.

Answer (score 0):

### Getting the fresh intent from the NFC foreground dispatch

In `onResume()` you retrieve the intent with `getIntent()`. Unless you overwrite this intent with `setIntent()`, `getIntent()` will return the intent that *initially* started your activity.

The fresh intent from the NFC foreground dispatch system is delivered to your activity through the `onNewIntent()` method. Therfore, you could do something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    doTagOperations(intent);
}
```

### The second NFC event launches a new instance of the activity

I'm not qute sure about that one, but my might want to try to experiment with setting the lauchMode for your activity. See [this answer to the question *NFC Tag Reading*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23302209/2425802). You could also try if the alternative approach to using the foreground dispatch system (using `createPendingResult()` and `onActivityResult()`) works in this situation. See [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28735334/2425802).